# What should be the order of things on an introduction to pure mathematics module?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, education

I want to produce a resource that has a narrative and includes the following topics:
Sets, logic and proofs, numbers (irrational, integers, rational, …), binomial theorem, geometric series, inequalities, define things like identity, polynomial, symmetry, sigma and product notation. 
It is in aid as an introduction to a number theory module.
How should I order these so that the end document has a narrative and is coherent, not just disjoint set of topics?

Comment: Maybe useful Larry Gerstein, [Introduction to Mathematical Structures and Proofs (Springer, 2012)](https://books.google.it/books?id=zqLoCAAAQBAJ&pg=PR8).

Comment: Integrate proofs into everything you write.

Comment: "How should I order these so that the end document has a narrative and is coherent, not just disjoint set of topics?" The order of the topics is not going to determine whether the document is a coherent narrative.

Comment: I suggest that you post this question on https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/.